# Jmeter 2.13 windows server compatibility for installation

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I would like to install Jmeter in windows server can any one help me which version of windows server in compatible for installation and detail requirments to install.

Thanks,
Venkatesh

Answer (score 1):

Any.

JMeter is a Java-based application so theoretically should run anywhere Java can run.

Just make sure you're:

- using latest [JMeter version](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)
- using latest [64-bit JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) or [Server JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html)

See [How to Get Started With JMeter: Part 1 - Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-part-1-installation-test-plans) article for detailed instructions.